# How to prevent the user from manually going to the url, requiring that they click a link to get there

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a website about a factory of chocolates, I'm working in Laravel and PHP. In my website I have a login, and different types of users.

Until there is every ok. If I login as an admin. The website shows the administration control panel as home page. In this site I have a menu with many operations for only admin users.

For example I have a menu about add new users. The url of the menu in the top bar navigation is:

```
localhost/BestChoco/NewUsers
```

And in this menu I have a button that redirect to another view that is a form to add new users.

Now th url is:

```
localhost/BestChoco/NewUsers/create
```

Is in this case, for example, I want to prevent the user, type in the top bar that url.

If the user type `localhost/BestChoco/NewUsers/create` in the top navigation bar, without visited the page of users, the website redirect automatically to the home page.

The home page is called `index.blade.php` Is the same for all user but the content changes depending on the user logged in. How can I do it?

Comment: What does this mean? "without checked the page of users", are they toggling a checkbox? Are they getting something from teh backend?

Comment: Are you saying that users should go to `BestChoco/NewUsers` before they go to `BestChoco/NewUsers/create` or are you saying you don't want to `allow certain users to be able to go to `BestChoco/NewUsers/create`?

Comment: Prevent them from typing it? No. You should always authenticate on requests to pages you want to protect, at the server level. If a user requests that url via postman or another get or post mechanism, you can't rely on client side checks for that. Authentication is a kinda big topic, and how you do it depends on a lot of things that won't fit in this comment box.

Comment: Yes, the page `BestChoco/NewUsers` containt a table of all registered users, only admins can view this page, and `BestChoco/NewUsers/create` is the form. Regardless of whether the logged in user is an admin. He can´t enter to that url `(BestChoco/NewUsers/create)` simply typing the url in the direction bar.

Comment: I was testing it, If I type localhost/BestChoco/NewUsers/create the webste show me the form to add new users. Previously having logged in as administrator.

Comment: In the controller displaying your index file you will want to utilize Laravel's built in `auth()` functions to check if a user has access, if not redirect them from the route, rather than redirecting from the blade page.

Comment: However you're authorizing your users and giving them admin access, you can also authorize them to have permissions to access, say, your `create` page. So just grant them those permissions when they visit the `NewUsers` page. You can't prevent them from entering the URL manually, but by only granting them permissions when they visit the `NewUsers` page, you can kick them back to the `NewUsers` page if they try to access `create` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The page cannot control default browser navigation bar behaviour.

You should be using a permissions-based method to kick unauthorized users out of that page if they manage to navigate there. You must manage this via your PHP code.